# java process and inputstream

Tags: java, eclipse, process

I'm developing a plugin for eclipse, in which process are running. I create a process and after I read its inputsream, but while the process and the inputstream are running, my eclipse platform can't answer for anything. So I would like to do a solution, when eclipse doesn't freeze. I think I should do this with java threads.

If somebody has an idea, describe that please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a separate thread to read the input stream.

To see an example of this, in Eclipse, do File -> Import -> Plug-in Development -> Plug-ins and Fragments.  Import from the active platform,  and import projects with source folders.  On the next tab, choose "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor".

Take a look at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.jarprocessor.StreamProcessor.  It runs in two modes, one using Jobs, the other using normal threads.  See the StreamProcessor getting used in CommandStep#execute